# How can I find particular table in database using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM server.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%table_name%'
```

I am using this query to list out the table names, which list all the table names in my SQL software. But the table name which I see in application-software is a different SQL-database table name. The displayed name and assigned (abbreviated) names are different and I can't correlate the found tables.

Does anyone have any idea how could I look for the right table?

Is there any way where I could see both displayed name and assigned name of the tables/columns?

Comment: MySQL only has 1 name for a table, so possibly your software is doning things behind the scenes.

Comment: *The displayed name and assigned (abbreviated) names are different and I can't corelate the found tables.* Either the relation is hardcoded in your application (read documentation for used framework in this case) or there exists a table with metadata (the relation between database tablename and one used in framework) - search for it.

Comment: well I am still new for mysql commands, i google to check for used framework, but still did not get any clue. Is there any other way, like comparing number of columns of the table to get better search results?

Comment: Maybe it is a view?

Comment: showing the result of your quey (the real table names), and what is shown in the application might give us some hints to help you more

Answer (score 0):

For searching tables (with their names) in particular database:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM DATABSE_NAME LIKE '%TABLE_NAME%';
```